# android issue : Textview marquee is not working

Tags: android

Section of my xml is :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/colorDeepGreen">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvModelMakeYear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_one"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added tvModelMakeYear.setSelected(true) within onCreate(). But still marquee is not working.

I am using Android Studio 2.3 ..

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: add tvModelMakeYear.setSingleLine(true); after tvModelMakeYear.setSelected(true), this should work. It will not show deprecated in the code.

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your code:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

and remove this line from the code:

```
android:lines="1"
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: I have tried this.But android:singleLine="true" is deprecated now.So I have used android:maxLines="1" as an alternative.Still marquee is not working :(

Comment: matquee is only working with singleline property not with lines property

Answer (score 0):

`android:singleLine` attribute has been deprecated since API Level 3, you can use

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Using Java you can use like

```
TextView textBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvModelMakeYear);
textBox.setMaxLines(1);
```

Comment: I have used this in xml. But still marquee is not working :(

Comment: android:focusable="true"    
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: added this twos line into textview